# Изменяющийся размер кнопок

Tags: android

Есть такая вёрстка Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="310dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="dfgdfdfdfgnfgnfgngfnfgfgnfgnnfgnfgngfnfg" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

В зависимости от ширины экрана размер кнопок разный, а нужно чтобы всегда был одинаковый. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: @GinTasan, их тут два один вложен в `ConstraintLayout`, другой в ` LinearLayout`, т.е они оба вложенные. Не могли бы Вы конкретизировать Ваш комментарий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил, надо просто убрать `android:layout_weight="1"` у кнопок

Comment: К слову, задать фиксированную ширину у контейнера, тоже помогает. Но вариант с `android:layout_weight="1"` ИМХО лучше.